# scroll to indexPath is not accurate on tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to scroll to a top of a section:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: sectionNum), at: .top, animated: true)
```

But the result is not accurate:

[image: screenshot]

The tableview section header is dynamic:

```
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 180
```

I've tested it without the dynamic header size and it worked - so this is the cause of the problem.

Even when I run the scroll in the viewDidAppear it's still not accurate.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Is the top of your tableView set to the top of the view or using the topLayoutGuide?

Comment: @Pierce yes it is

Comment: Which one? Because if it's set to the top of the view, that means the top of your tableView is set to the very top of the screen, which means it's actually partially behind the navigation bar at the top. You might try setting it's y-value on it's frame to `topLayoutGuide.length`

Comment: Do you see what I'm saying? It is scrolling to the top of the cell you tell it to, but part of that cell is stuck behind the navigationBar. If you do use the topLayoutGuide, make sure to do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` because in `viewDidLoad` it's still equal to zero

Comment: I don't think it's the case because it's not always the same padding problem.   I know In the example screenshot it looks like the size of the navigation bar, but sometimes the padding is different. It's not a fixed size difference.

Comment: What about the content size of the table? Is there more content below what is shown in the screen shot or does it show the last cell?

Comment: @gkchristopher yes there is more content

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `estimatedSectionHeaderHeight` to different values? If the header is scrolling onto screen, it may be using the estimated value since it may not have calculated subview positions yet.